# How to draw a doughnut?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please help me fix code. I use D3 v5.7.0 and i try draw doughnut.

Live demo [is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/38hqfdbm/29/)

My code is here:

```
const dataset = [
  [ 5,   3 ]
];


const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "outer-circle")
   .attr("cx", 110)
   .attr("cy", 110)
   .attr("r", 10);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "inner-circle")
   .attr("cx", 110)
   .attr("cy", 110)
   .attr("r", 5);
```

But browser display single black circle. Its problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do. You're attaching the dataset, but you don't seem to be using it.

I'm assuming you want to, so here's an example using the data for the radius. Notice the css: it uses `fill` for the color not `background`.

You can also use `fill` and `stroke` instead of two circles.

```js
const dataset = [ 5,   3 ];

const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);
            
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", 110)
   .attr("cy", 110)
   .attr("r", function(d) { return d * 5})
   .attr("class", function(d, i) {
      return i ? "inner-circle": "outer-circle"
      })
```

```css
svg {
  background: cyan;
}

.inner-circle {
  fill: white;
}

.outer-circle {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of background in your css you should use fill like this :

```
fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
```

And what is that dataset doing there ? here is a simple doughnut by some edits to your code :

```js
const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

svg.append("circle")
   .attr("class", "outer-circle")
   .attr("cx", 110)
   .attr("cy", 110)
   .attr("r", 10)

svg.append("circle")
   .attr("class", "inner-circle")
   .attr("cx", 110)
   .attr("cy", 110)
   .attr("r", 5)
```

```css
svg {
  background: cyan;
}

.inner-circle {
  fill: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.outer-circle {
  fill: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[D3 Donut Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) is a better/flexible/standard approach to draw a donut chart in d3 i.e. using [d3 shape -arcs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arcs) and [d3 shapes - pies](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arcs).

Here's a snippet using the above arc and pie generators and the dataset that you provide and drawing a donut out of it: (I'm using [d3.schemeCategory10](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic#schemeCategory10) to add colors to the arcs.

```js
var dataset = [5, 3];

var height = 300,
 width = 800,
  radius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
  
var colorSchema = d3.schemeCategory10;

var arc = d3.arc()
 .outerRadius(radius-10)
  .innerRadius(radius-40);
  
var pie = d3.pie()
 .sort(null)
  .value(function (d)  { return d; });
  
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
 .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);
  
var g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate('+(width/2)+','+(height/2)+')');

var path = g.selectAll('.arc')
 .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append('g').classed('arc', true);

path.append('path').attr('d', arc).attr('fill', function(d, i) { return colorSchema[i];});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

And adding some more values to the dataset, here's another snippet:

```js
var dataset = [5, 3, 10, 20, 8];

var height = 300,
 width = 800,
  radius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
  
var colorSchema = d3.schemeCategory10;

var arc = d3.arc()
 .outerRadius(radius-10)
  .innerRadius(radius-40);
  
var pie = d3.pie()
 .sort(null)
  .value(function (d)  { return d; });
  
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
 .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);
  
var g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate('+(width/2)+','+(height/2)+')');

var path = g.selectAll('.arc')
 .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append('g').classed('arc', true);

path.append('path').attr('d', arc).attr('fill', function(d, i) { return colorSchema[i];});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I see that you've accepted an answer but I wanted to let you know about this approach as well which gives a lot of flexibility. Hope this helps too.